# Assign checkbox value to an object in session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a big object in my session which I am using to display on jsp page, Now the problem is this object has a List which contains object with status selected. I want to change the boolean selected value when I select the checkbox. How can I achieve this?

Lets say I have a POJO which internally has multiple list of OTHER_POJOs, now each of these internal OTHER_POJO will have a selected boolean flag. Now I am able to display the OUTER most POJO on page but I want to manipulate the "selected" property based on the checkbox value that user is going to select/unselect. Now the question is the OUTER POJO is available in session, how can I change the selected values of INTERNAL POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

you can set those internal pojo attributes value in session as well. 
OR
you can set internal pojo into session object.

Comment: why to set it separately if surrounding OUTER pojo is already in session?? I Need a way to modify its attribute from jsp it self.

Comment: so.. if you dont want to set those internal pojo into session , then you have work with outer as well as internal POJO.which will make your code in lots of line... and if you will go with my suggestion your code will be done in less ammount of code.

Comment: No, I think you are not getting what I am saying, I get the value of inner pojos like this. OUTER_POJO.internalPojoList.tempInternalPojo this goes in a c:forEach where I iterate and display columns with checkbox now on select of this checkbox I want to modify the value OUTER_POJO.internalPojoList.tempInternalPojo.selected, I think this is possible as I can access the object on jsp but don't know how.

Comment: have you tried with your approach that you are telling...OUTER_POJO.internalPojoList.tempInternalPojo.selected

Comment: How to assign selected checkbox value to this OUTER_POJO.internalPojoList.tempInternalPojo.selected??

Comment: In this case you have to call ajax. using javascript create a function on check box clicked. get those values into javascript and call your action class by ajax call .. retrieve those selected check box values into action and create a pojo object into that class and assign those values into pojo. and recieve the response from ajax.

Comment: No, I don't need JS based answer I want java specific using JSTL/Scriplets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68720/discussion-between-arvind-vishwakarma-and-samwise-gamgee).